# Can't find the saved variables

Tags: tensorflow

The variable `saver` program is as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

raw_data = [1., 2., 8., -1., 0., 5.5, 6., 13]
spikes = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
spikes.initializer.run()

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()  #add by cs
saver = tf.train.Saver()
for i in range(1, len(raw_data)):
if raw_data[i] - raw_data[i-1] > 5:
    spikes_val = spikes.eval()
    spikes_val[i] = True
    updater = tf.assign(spikes, spikes_val)
    updater.eval()

save_path = saver.save(sess, "spikes.ckpt")
print("spikes data saved in file: %s" % save_path)

sess.close()
```

the restore program is as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

spikes = tf.Variable([False]*8, name='spikes')
saver = tf.train.Saver()

try:
   saver.restore(sess, 'spikes.ckpt')
   print(spikes.eval())
except:
   print('file not found')

sess.close()
```

there is always an exception `"file not found"`.

What's wrong?

Comment: make sure that file exists. the errors indicate you are not giving proper file path.

Comment: dear ishant mrinal . the "saver program" and the "restore program" are in the same folder, and when i run the "saver program", i can find the file "spikes.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001“ ”spikes.ckpt.index“ and "spikes.ckpt.meta"